# Grails 2.2.4 testing what does assert means and response url

Tags: grails, testing, groovy

I do not understand clearly the code behind the "assert". Please tell me what does those mean.
I already put the params attribute above my code . I did not describe detail.

```
void testSave() {
    controller.save()
    println 'testSave() from Controller'
    assert model.serviceAccountInstance != null
    assert view == '/serviceAccount/create'

    response.reset()

    populateValidParams(params)
    controller.save()
    println params.passWord
    assert response.redirectedUrl == '/serviceAccount/show/1'
    assert controller.flash.message != null
    assert ServiceAccount.count() == 1
}
```

Than you for your answer.

Comment: Can you a bit more specific and define a clear question? What is it you don't understand?

Comment: assert throws AssertionError when the 'code behind it' evalutes to false.

Comment: you mean AssertionError will generate if the serviceAccountInstance  is null. And then what is the response.redirectedUrl , please. currently I could not test the GSP.

Comment: I have this domain ServiceAccount . In my testSave() method model.serviceAccountInstance != null  how can I test that?Then assert view == '/serviceAccount/create' will go to create gsp like that?